# How do I create shortcuts to Cygwin programs in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-xp, cygwin, shortcuts

I would like to create a Windows shortcut to launch Linux applications through Cygwin. The Cygwin X server is installed and running but I can't figure out a way to do it.

I'd like to have shortcuts/launchers for Geaany and the Xfce4 Terminal, which were installed via the Cygwin ports.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Geaany or the Xfce4 terminal, but Cygwin programs are Windows programs.  You can start them in the same way as any other Windows program.

For example, to start mintty from your desktop, you can create a shortcut to c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe.  That's all there is to it.

If your programs need to run with command line arguments, you can include the arguments in the command line in the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

- Write a script to execute Geaany or Xfce4 in notepad save it as sh extension and chose to open with bash in cygwin directory.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea but I don't get it completely. Care to elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: Example => 

open Notepad and write this

Comment: man mv         (STOP) do not write (STOP) then save it as sh ext and start with bash.exe in cygwin directory.